# socat equivalent of netcat -N

Tags: netcat, socat

I have a dumb network service that receives an entire file up to EOF and then emits a response.

I can use it like this:

```
netcat -N $SERVER $PORT < input > output
```

netcat's `-N` option causes a `shutdown(..., SHUT_WR)` to be send when the file is read, so that the server will process and send the output.

I can't find a socat equivalent.

It is something like:

```
socat - TCP:$SERVER:$PORT,linger=5000,shut-down < input > output
```

but I never manage to get the response data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small python server which after discussion minimally mimics the server you describe.

```
import asyncio
import time

class FileReceiver(asyncio.Protocol):

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        print("connection_made")
        self.transport = transport

    def data_received(self, data):
        print(data)

    def eof_received(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        self.transport.write("hello\n".encode());
        if self.transport.can_write_eof():
            self.transport.write_eof()
        return True    

async def main(host, port):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    server = await loop.create_server(FileReceiver, host, port)
    await server.serve_forever()

asyncio.run(main('127.0.0.1', 5000))
```

It correctly returns the hello\n with

```
netcat -N $SERVER $PORT < input > output
```

does not return the hello\n when -N is dropped

```
netcat $SERVER $PORT < input > output
```

but does not work with

```
socat - TCP:$SERVER:$PORT < input > output
```

socat by default sends the SHUT_WR so shut-down is not needed, the shutdowns are the same for netcat -N and socat. The problem is in the timing. socat works if the time.sleep is excluded so socat is shutting down too quickly. The default delay for socat to shutdown the channel is 0.5 second. This can be extended with the -t option. The following works correctly.

```
socat -t 5 - TCP:$SERVER:$PORT < input > output
```

Comment: I am very grateful for the trouble you went to. After adding to your example (after `print("eof")` the line `self.transport.write("hello\n".encode());` I find that the socat example does dump the output "hello", but if I also *first* add the line `time.sleep(2)` (followed by the transport.write) then I find that `socat` does not output "hello" but `netcat -N` does. (socat version 1.7.3.2). socat closes the connection early causing errors in your python server that netcat does not cause. I can't find a way to stop socat doing this.

Comment: Ah, that helps. so you need a longer delay before it shuts down. That is the -t option to socat.

Comment: I have edited the answer to reflect the discussion.

Comment: thanks - this is what I needed. It seems that -t is an idle timeout, which is not made clear in the man page. 

"When one channel has reached EOF, the write part  of  the  other channel is shut down. Then, socat waits <timeout> [timeval] seconds before terminating." should probably be "waits for <timeout> [timeval] seconds of inactivity before terminating"

I find that so as long as t is sufficiently large, it doesn't matter how long the response takes, as long as it makes progress compared with the -t value.

Great answer, thank-you.